# Filter posts by their related field's custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, filters, advanced-custom-fields

I have two post types named 'programs' and 'universities', where the programs are connected to their respective universities.

I want to filter programs by university's custom fields such as ranking or location.

I can filter and display the programs by their own custom fields using WP_Query. However, I cannot filter them by their related post's (university's) custom field.

```
<?php

$args=array(
        "post_type" => 'programs',
    );

//filter by custom field
if(isset($_GET['shift']))
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'shift',
        'value' => $shift,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );

//filtered by taxonomy
if(isset($terms1))
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $terms1,
        'operator' => 'IN',

// Don't know how to filter by related post's custom fields

$proSearch_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($proSearch_query->have_posts()){
    $proSearch_query->the_post();

            $result[] = array(
            "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "rel_university" => get_field('uni')[0]->post_name,
                //returns related post's custom field:
                "ranking" => get_field('university')[0]->ranking,
            );
}
echo json_encode($result);
die(); 
?>
```

Comment: I think that neither WP_Query nor other part of wordpress core will help you to do this filter. then the first step is to retrieve all programs with [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and walk on the programs list to filter them. if this uses too much resources, you can use a cache like saving university's properties (only ranking and location if you don't need more) in each program of this university.

Comment: I have another idea : when the user selects ranking and location, the first step is to search all universities with theses properties and then you search programs list of theses universities.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to query posts multiple times. Can you illustrate with code or send me some references?

Comment: It looks like you are grouping universities and programs by their rankings/locations/etc, is there a reason you used post meta to store this data? The "taxonomy" or grouping based data storage of custom taxonomies would have been orders of magnitude faster. Post meta queries are exceptionally slow, the post meta table is optimised for finding meta values when you already know the post ID and meta key. Using it to search for post IDs is not what it was built for, thats why taxonomies use their own table

Comment: Seriously consider a `ranking` or `location` taxonomy instead, it could be 100-1000x faster, and easier to query for. If you're using ACF you can configure the field to use a taxonomy instead of post meta to store the values. A general guide is that if you ever want to search for things based on a field, filter them out, etc, use a custom taxonomy. Post meta is for storing specifics when you already know which post

Comment: @TomJNowell The question again rises towards filtering by taxonomy of the related field, since I cannot assign taxonomies to both post types when there are hundreds of posts. Also, rankings for each university would be unique. Perhaps there might be a way to filter post data inside jQuery ajax itself rather than filtering them in a callback.

Comment: Oh but you **can**, afterall how is it any different to what you're doing with post meta? I also don't see how unique rankings would be an issue, there's nothing bad about terms that only contain a single post if it's saving you a post meta query, afterall we don't complain about post meta values that only occur once. Even just converting one post field to a taxonomy would be an **enormous** performance boost

Comment: Thanks, get_post has solved the issue. I would consider taxonomy too for location and other fields. However not sure about ranking.